# How can I convert ClusterIp to NodePort in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to convert from ClusterIp to NodePort. But When I call via curl http://176.55.116.xxx:30100 . It creates the below error. How can I convert below from clusterIp to Nodeport version?

[image: Unable o connect to remote server when using curl to call http://176.55.116.116:30100] below configuration is not working...

**(1) ClusterIp version (deployment_service.yml) [WORKING] **

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  namespace: coturn
  name: coturn
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
spec:
  # replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
          app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
            app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
            app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      # securityContext:
      #   runAsUser: 1000
      #   runAsGroup: 1000
      containers:
        - name: coturn
          image: coturn/coturn
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            # - name: turn-udp
            #   containerPort: 3000
            #   protocol: UDP
            - name: turn-port1
              containerPort: 3478
              hostPort: 3478
              protocol: UDP
            - name: turn-port2
              containerPort: 3478
              hostPort: 3478
              protocol: TCP
          # securityContext:
          #   capabilities:
          #     drop:
          #       - ALL
            # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            # allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          args:
          #   - --stun-only
            - -v

--- 

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: coturn
  namespace: coturn
  labels:
       app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
       app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
       app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    # - port: 3000
    #   targetPort: 3000
    #   protocol: UDP
    #   name: turn-udp
    - port: 3478
      targetPort: 3478
      protocol: UDP
      name: turn-port1
    - port: 3478
      targetPort: 3478
      protocol: TCP
      name: turn-port2
    # - port: 3478
    #   targetPort: 3478
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   name: turn-port3
    # - port: 3479
    #   targetPort: 3479
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   name: turn-port4
    
  selector:
       app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
       app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
       app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
```

**(2) NodePort version (deployment_service.yml) :   (NOT WORKInG)**

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  namespace: coturn
  name: coturn
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
spec:
  # replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
          app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
            app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
            app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      # securityContext:
      #   runAsUser: 1000
      #   runAsGroup: 1000
      containers:
        - name: coturn
          image: coturn/coturn
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            # - name: turn-udp
            #   containerPort: 3000
            #   protocol: UDP
            - name: turn-port1
              containerPort: 3478
              hostPort: 3478
              protocol: UDP
            - name: turn-port2
              containerPort: 3478
              hostPort: 3478
              protocol: TCP
          # securityContext:
          #   capabilities:
          #     drop:
          #       - ALL
            # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            # allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          args:
          #   - --stun-only
            - -v

--- 

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: coturn
  namespace: coturn
  labels:
       app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
       app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
       app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    # - port: 3000
    #   targetPort: 3000
    #   protocol: UDP
    #   name: turn-udp
    - port: 3478
      targetPort: 3478
      nodePort: 30100
      protocol: UDP
      name: turn-port1
    - port: 3478
      targetPort: 3478
      nodePort: 30100
      protocol: TCP
      name: turn-port2
    selector:
      app: coturn
    # - port: 3478
    #   targetPort: 3478
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   name: turn-port3
    # - port: 3479
    #   targetPort: 3479
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   name: turn-port4
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**Error:**

```sh
yusuf@DESKTOP-QK5VI8R:~/turnserver$ kubectl apply -f deploy.yml
daemonset.apps/coturn created
error: error parsing deploy.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 27: did not find expected '-' indicator
```

Comment: Which of the files are `deploy.yaml` that gives you the error when applied?

Comment: @danielorn  last deploy.yml is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the `yaml` syntax, the selector is under `spec.ports`, which cannot work.

This is the corrected file (to check problems, use YAML validators, there are plenty online which you can toy with):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  namespace: coturn
  name: coturn
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
spec:
  # replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
          app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
            app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
            app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      # securityContext:
      #   runAsUser: 1000
      #   runAsGroup: 1000
      containers:
        - name: coturn
          image: coturn/coturn
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            # - name: turn-udp
            #   containerPort: 3000
            #   protocol: UDP
            - name: turn-port1
              containerPort: 3478
              hostPort: 3478
              protocol: UDP
            - name: turn-port2
              containerPort: 3478
              hostPort: 3478
              protocol: TCP
          # securityContext:
          #   capabilities:
          #     drop:
          #       - ALL
            # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            # allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          args:
          #   - --stun-only
            - -v
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: coturn
  namespace: coturn
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: coturn
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: coturn
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    # - port: 3000
    #   targetPort: 3000
    #   protocol: UDP
    #   name: turn-udp
    - port: 3478
      targetPort: 3478
      nodePort: 30100
      protocol: UDP
      name: turn-port1
    - port: 3478
      targetPort: 3478
      nodePort: 30100
      protocol: TCP
      name: turn-port2
    # - port: 3478
    #   targetPort: 3478
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   name: turn-port3
    # - port: 3479
    #   targetPort: 3479
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   name: turn-port4
  selector:
    app: coturn
```